# NameError: name 'name' is not defined in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

Hello i am learning tkinter and I can't solve this problem when I run this program.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
'''
    master = tk.Tk()

```
class App():

def __init__(self, master):
    self.pocetnik_label = Label(master, text = 'Pocetnik')
    self.pocetnik_label.pack(side = LEFT)

    self.dodaj_button = Button(master, text = '+', command = pocetnik(self))
    self.dodaj_button.pack(side = RIGHT)

def pocetnik(self):
    master.widnows = tk.Toplevel(master)
    self.ime_label = Label(pocetnik, text = 'Ime').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.ime_entry = Entry(pocetnik, bd = 5).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

pocetnik = App(master) 
master.mainloop()
```

When I run it I get this error:
NameError: name 'pocetnik' is not defined

Comment: `pocetnik` and `self. pocetnik` are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> from tkinter import *
> from tkinter import ttk
> import tkinter as tk
> class App(ttk.Frame):
>
>   def __init__(self, master):
>       self.newwindow=master
>       self.pocetnik_label = Label(master, text = 'Pocetnik')
>       self.pocetnik_label.pack(side = LEFT)
>
>       self.dodaj_button = Button(master, text = '+', command =self.pocetnik)
>       self.dodaj_button.pack(side = RIGHT)
>       self.newwindow.mainloop()
>
>   def pocetnik(self):
>       b2= tk.Toplevel(self.newwindow)
>       self.ime_label = Label(b2, text = 'Ime').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
>       self.ime_entry = Entry(b2, bd = 5).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
>
> master=Tk()
> pocetnik = App(master)
> ```

test now